# How to replace Environment Variables of an Azure Function in Release Pipeline on VSTS

Tags: azure, .net-core, environment-variables, azure-functions, continuous-delivery

I developed an Azure Function and I need to use the Build and Release Pipelines of VSTS (Azure DevOps) to do the CI/CD.

To be able to use the same Build in different environments, I am using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyVariable")` to get the value of some variables.

I am able to configure those variables on the Application Settings of the Azure Function, and I am also able to use the VSTS release pipeline to replace those values on the Application Settings.

However, due to security reasons imposed by my client, I cannot have those variables available to be seen at the Application Settings.

So I need to, somehow, use the  Build/Release pipeline to set the environment variables and not make them readable on the function resource at the Azure Portal.

What is the most elegant way to do it?

I am using Azure Functions 2.0

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use [Azure Keyvault to store secrets and access into your Azure functions](https://rahulpnath.com/blog/azure-key-vault-from-azure-functions/) then you can get the values from [your vsts and assign it](https://colinsalmcorner.com/post/managing-credentials-and-secrets-in-vsts-release-management)

Comment: But in this way the secrets will be visible at the Application Settings on the resource, right?

Comment: No It's not,in fact all the secrets will be stored in Azure KeyVault, they never exposed to application settings

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? @ArturQuirino